# PHP, Classes and Objects

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, oop

I,m trying to list all the names from a  json database to html using a class. the html output should look something like this:-

> **Characters**
>
> - name: John
> - name: Sarah
> - name: Michael

I've managed to reach this far with my code. I know this code is not finished or it is has errors but I'm still a beginner and learning. Can you please help me get this code to work?

**Json database file**

> databas.json

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "height": "182 cm",
        "mass": "80 kg",
    },
    {
        "name": "Sarah",
        "height": "165 kg",
        "mass": "60 cm",
    },
    {
        "name": "Michael",
        "height": "178 cm",
        "mass": "75 kg",
    },
    ]
}
```

**Index file**

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <title>Character</title>

    </head>

    <body style="margin-bottom:20em;">
        <h1>Characters</h1>
            <?php include('characters.php'); ?>

            <?php 
            $data = file_get_contents("databs.json");
            $data = json_decode($data, true);

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';

            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Class code**

> characters.php

```
<?php

class Character {

        private $name;

public function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;

        }
public function getName($name){
        return $this->name;
        }

}
 ?>
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything with JSON or a database. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do, and add any other relevant code?

Comment: `see where the problem is`: how do you expect us to do that without providing any details on intended purpose, MCVE and actual outputs vs expected outputs ?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in my question. I've edited my question and I hope if you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access variable using getter setter method only then use private scope instead of public.

And your method should be public.

```
<?php

class Character {

        private $name;

public function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;

        }
public function getName($name){
        return $this->name;
        }

}
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful but I still can make it work. I've edited my question and I hope if you can help or just point out where the errors are. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your objects should always be private and your functions should be public(so you can access them).  This is a reason as to why you build a constructor.  Assuming that the object is $name, you should be able to get access to it by changing that.